# DNS Look up does not show if domain starts with www

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I am a little confused about DNS look up. If I add 'www' to the domain while looking up I see no records. But if I remove 'www' from the domain and then query, I see the DNS records.

[DNS Propagation Checker](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/codeproject.com) (shows records)
[DNS Propagation Checker](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/www.codeproject.com) (no records)

Why does this happen?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, because I AM getting A records for www.codeproject.com. Ergo - can not repro.

Comment: @TomTom based on the links it looks like the question is about `NS` records. Ie, completely expected if `www` is part of the same zone.

Comment: Yes I am asking about NS records. Why doesn't it show up for 'www'

Comment: Ah. Ok, valid question then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lookups indicated in the question are for `NS` records.

`NS` records are used for delegating zones to the authoritative nameservers and exist at the starting point of each zone.

In your example, `codeproject.com` is the starting point of a zone (ie, it's separate from the `com` zone) but `www.codeproject.com` is just a name inside the `codeproject.com` zone and thus has no `NS` records of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Your domain without www, has `ns` :

```
 # dig codeproject.com ns

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-12.1-Debian <<>> codeproject.com ns
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19623
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;codeproject.com.       IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
codeproject.com.    229 IN  NS  ns1.easydns.com.
codeproject.com.    229 IN  NS  service1.codeproject.com.
codeproject.com.    229 IN  NS  ns2.easydns.com.
codeproject.com.    229 IN  NS  service2.codeproject.com.

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 85.15.1.15#53(85.15.1.15)
;; WHEN: Mon May 09 02:11:48 IRDT 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 134
```

But your domain with www, doesn't has `ns`:

```
# dig www.codeproject.com ns

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-12.1-Debian <<>> www.codeproject.com ns
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29227
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.codeproject.com.       IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
codeproject.com.    299 IN  SOA service1.codeproject.com. david.cunningham.codeproject.com. 2016020214 7200 1200 432000 300

;; Query time: 173 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon May 09 02:13:14 IRDT 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 110
```